# Excel VBA runs differently on 2 machines

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code in excel that is doing different things on 2 machines. The file is the exact same. What the code is doing is running through a series of IDs. If it finds a matching ID, it skips it. If there is no matching ID, it adds the new one to the bottom. This code works correctly on my machine but not my colleagues. We both have Excel 10, 32 bit and VBA7 (I checked because I thought this might be the issue) Can anyone thing of something else it could be?

```
Sheets("Summary").Select
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox (lastRow)

Sheets("DeSL_Prod").Select
Dim lastPRODRow As Long
lastPRODRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox (lastPRODRow)


Dim strVal As String
Dim ranA As Range

For Each ranA In Range("A2:A" & lastPRODRow) ' add any new productid that wasn't already on the list
    strVal = ranA
    If strVal > "" Then
        With Sheets("Summary").Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
            If .Find(What:=strVal, _
                     LookIn:=xlValues, _
                     LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then _
                Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & lastRow + 1).End(xlUp).Range("A2") = strVal
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        End With
     End If
 Next ranA
```

Comment: What is the expected output and the incorrect output?

Comment: What exactly is it doing differently? Maybe show the two different results. Make sure to point out which one is incorrect.

Comment: ... or at least the one that IS correct.

Comment: Sorry, thought that was clear. When I run it, it skips any ID that is already on the spreadsheet. On hers it duplicates the ID.

Answer (score 1):

The [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) 'remembers' what has been done on the application's worksheet interface by the user. Your colleague may habitually leave the Match Case options checked or find that searching by format is often easier. You are inheriting these options since you are not explicitly defining those options, they may be turned on without you realizing.

In short, control the environment you are using to search under by specifying any and all options that could affect the outcome.

```
    With Sheets("Summary").Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        If .Find(What:=strVal, _
                 LookIn:=xlValues, _
                 LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                 MatchCase:=False, _
                 SearchFormat:=False) Is Nothing Then
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
            Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & lastRow).End(xlUp).Range("A2") = strVal
        End If
    End With
```

You seemed to incrementing the *lastRow* var whether it was used to place a value or not. I've modified the code so that it only increments when the value is copied across.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped but the problem persists! On my computer my code and your code works fine: IDs that are already in the spreadsheet are skipped and only new ones are added. On my colleages computer, existing IDs are duplicated and new ones added.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if both machines have the same configuration for Region and Language (Control Panel -> Clock,Language, and Region).
Sometimes you have the same number but distincts formats (example: 1.234,5 in brazilian format and 1,234.5 in US format). Although they are mathematically equal, Excel may consider them distinct.

This apply to .Find method.